# WPF TabControl with Tabs on the left and two columns

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I would like to be able to have a tab control with the tab strip placement set to left and the tab items turned 270 degrees but I would like the tab items to create a new column when they run off the bottom of the window, exactly like they do when they run off the side of the window when in the standard horizontal orientation and tabs placed on the top.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189370/how-to-put-wpf-tab-control-tabs-on-the-side

Comment: Johnny, that question covers the tabs on the side and rotated which I can get to work, I cannot make it have more than one column of tabs.